# Scraping wine data from Vivino using Python

Tags: python, scrape

I'm trying to extract a large amount of data from Vivino using the code below. After 2000 records (ie 80 pages with 25 records/page), the request returns the same dataset whatever the page number you set in the payload (page > 80).
Does anyone have an idea where this limitation comes from ? from the api itself ? from my code ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import pandas as pd
# Import packages
import requests

payload = {
    "country_code": "FR",
    "country_codes[]": "fr",
    "currency_code": "EUR",
    "grape_filter": "varietal"
}

# Get request from the Vivino website
r = requests.get(
    "https://www.vivino.com/api/explore/explore",
    params=payload,
    headers={
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"
    },
)

n_matches = r.json()['explore_vintage']['records_matched']
print(f'Number of matches: {n_matches}')

# Iterates through the amount of possible pages
results = []

for i in range(1, max(1, int(n_matches / 25)) + 1):
    # Adds the page to the payload
    payload['page'] = i
    print(f'Scraping data from page: {payload["page"]}')

    r = requests.get(
        "https://www.vivino.com/api/explore/explore",
        params=payload,
        headers={
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"
        },
    )

    # Variables to __scrape__ from the Vivino website
    for t in r.json()["explore_vintage"]["matches"]:
        #        print(f'Nom du vin: {t["vintage"]["name"]}')
        #        print(f'Region du vin: {t["vintage"]["wine"]["style"]["name"]}')

        try:
            bottle_small = f"https:{t['vintage']['image']['variations']['bottle_small']}"
        except:
            bottle_small = ""

        try:
            regional_name = t["vintage"]["wine"]["style"]["regional_name"]
        except:
            regional_name = ""

        try:
            varietal_name = t["vintage"]["wine"]["style"]["varietal_name"]
        except:
            varietal_name = ""

        result = (
            t["vintage"]["id"],
            t["vintage"]["name"],
            t["vintage"]["wine"]["winery"]["name"],
            t["vintage"]["wine"]["name"],
            t["vintage"]["year"],
            t["vintage"]["wine"]["region"]["name"],
            regional_name,
            varietal_name,
            t["vintage"]["statistics"]["ratings_average"],
            bottle_small,
            f"https:{t['vintage']['image']['location']}"
        )
        results.append(result)

# Saving the results in a dataframe
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(
    results,
    columns=["Wine Id", "Wine Full Name", "Winery", "Wine Name", "Year", "Appellation", "Region", "Sous-Region", "Rating", "Image Small", "Image"],
)
dataframe.to_csv(f"data.csv", index=False)
```

I have tried starting the extract from page 80 and the issue comes immediately.